# Custom date format in emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to have something like "Dec 15, 2011"

Emacs org-mode only lets me toggle between <11/29/13 Fri> and <2013-11-29 Fri>.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use org-mode myself, but `M-x apropos-variable org.*time` turned up a couple of likely suspects.  (I tried `org.*date` first, but that didn't produce anything useful.)

It looks like you want to set `org-display-custom-times` to `t` and set `org-time-stamp-custom-formats` to the way you want them displayed.

The value of `org-time-stamp-custom-formats` appears to be a cons cell, where the car is the format for a date, and the cdr is the format for a date+time.

So I would try

```
(setq-default org-display-custom-times t)
(setq org-time-stamp-custom-formats '("<%b %e, %Y>" . "<%b %e, %Y %H:%M>"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You suggestion is being rendered as <b 21, %>
for 21 November. I think it is not recognizing %b. Any fixes?

Comment: @shyamupa, apparently, the `<>` are mandatory, or org-mode doesn't work right.  I put them back in, and it seems to work.

Comment: Further experimentation shows that org-mode seems to overwrite the first & last character of your format with `<>`.  `"<%b %e, %Y>"`, `" %b %e, %Y "`, and `"[%b %e, %Y]"` all seem to produce `<Dec 11, 2013>`.